# Hacer multiple insert con checkbox

Tags: php, jquery

Solo e podido realizar insert pero de solo uno, al seleccionar varias personas quiero que se haga el insert de las que estan seleccionadas ya sean 3, 4, 5 ,etc. es en MVC

EL html

```
<?php foreach($todo_personas as $todo): ?>
          <?php 

     //print_r($todo);

?>
<td><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1"id= "<?=$todo->id_persona;?>" value="<?=$todo->id_persona;?>"> </td>

      <?php endforeach ?>
```

/* --------------------------------- */

```
    $('.checkbox1').on('click', function(e){
        id = $(this).val();
        $('#id').val(id);
});
```

ajax

```
$('.boton').click(function(){
        var id = $('#id').val();         
        var persona = $('#persona').val();
        var fecha = $('#fecha').val();
        var ciudad = $('#ciudad').val();

    if(inv !='' && fecha !='' && persona !=''){
        $.ajax({
           url: base_url + "contacto/persona",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data : {persona,persona},
            success: function(json, textStatus, jqXHR){
                console.log(json);

                console.log(json.status);
                if (json.status) {
                    registrar(id,persona,fecha);
                }else{
                    swal('Error!', 'no se encuentra', 'error');
                    console.log(json.status);
                }
                },
                complete: function(textStatus, jqXHR){
            },
            error: function(textStatus, errorThrown, jqXHR){
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
                console.log(jqXHR);

            }

        });
    }else{
        swal('Error!', 'Favor de llenar todos los campos', 'error');
    }
});
```

Funcion

```
    function registrar(id,persona,fecha)
 {

            $.ajax({
               url: base_url + "contacto/registrar",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data : {id : id, persona : persona, fecha : fecha},
                success: function(json){
                swal('Bien!', 'Se a enviado ', 'success').then(function(){
                    });
                },
                complete: function(textStatus, jqXHR) {
                },
                error: function(textStatus, errorThrown, jqXHR){
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                }
                });

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array__ = [];
  $.each($(".checkbox1"),function(index,val){
    console.log($(val).prop("checked"));
    if($(val).prop("checked")==true){
      array__.push($(val).val());
    }
});

console.log(array__);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="checkbox1" checked type="checkbox" id= "1" value="valor1">

<input class="checkbox1" checked type="checkbox" id= "2" value="valor2">

<input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" id= "3" value="valor3">

<input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" id= "4" value="valor4">
```

Luego en el ajax debes enviar el array como parametro en el data:

data:{persona:persona,seleccionados: array__}

Esta data llega como un array a PHP donde puedes jugar con la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Agarre parte de tu códgio y emule la tabla con datos ficticios, y en cada fila coloque un checkbox, luego al final coloque un botón para obtener los **checkbox** que estén chequedos o `:checked`; si te fijas dicho botón posee un evento click que es la parte donde te tienes que guiar el cual recorro todos los checbox con la clase `.checkbox1` que esten chequeados, si exite alguno obtengo todos los valores de su fila y los almaceno en un arreglo que tiene como nombre `arrayFila`, cabe resaltar que cada vez que lleno el array es un valor o un array tipo **json**, por lo que te llegará así al PHP. En el php lo recorreras con un foreach o un for como se te sea mejor y cada indice como su valor es un json deberás de tratarlo como tal osea colocarle un `json_decode()` para poder obtener sus valores.

**P.D:** Coloque un `console.log(arrayFila)` para que puedas ver como se va llenando dicho array, y en el ajax fijate como lo estoy pasando en `data`.

```js
$("#guardar").on("click", () => {

  var arrayFila = [];
  
  $(".checkbox1:checked").each((indice, elemento) => {
    let fila = $(elemento).parents("tr");
    let id = $(elemento).val();
    let persona = fila.find(".persona").val();
    let fecha = fila.find(".fecha").val();
    let ciudad = fila.find(".ciudad").val();
    
    arrayFila.push({id:id, persona:persona, fecha:fecha, ciudad:ciudad});
  });
  
  console.log(arrayFila);
  let base_url  = "";
  $.ajax({
    url: base_url + "contacto/registrar",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data : {personas : arrayFila},
    success: function(json){},
    complete: function(textStatus, jqXHR) {},
    error: function(textStatus, errorThrown, jqXHR){}
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="persona" value="David Molina">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="fecha" value="02/10/2018">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="ciudad" value="Caracas">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="1" value="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="persona" value="Leonardo Ruíz">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="fecha" value="01/10/2018">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="ciudad" value="Valencia">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="1" value="2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="persona" value="Freddy Manuel">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="fecha" value="03/10/2018">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="ciudad" value="Bejuma">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="1" value="3">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <button id="guardar">Guardar</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```